# interval of convergence of $e^x$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Can somebody explain how to find the interval of convergence for
$$
e^x=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n!}
$$
I don't fully understand the ratio test/root test/integral test etc. and I don't understand what values to "pull" to get the final answer for the interval of convergance of $e^x$.

Comment: what are you having difficulty with?

Comment: @IttayWeiss I understand the limit of convergence will be:

lim x --> infinity |(e^(x+1))/(e^x)|

but what does that mean? what values do I take from that?

Comment: I assume you are asking about the convergence of the series for $e^x$. What convergence tests have you learned? ratio test? root test? integral test?

Comment: @robjohn I have heard of all of them but don't understand them clearly.  I'm also currently working on a question which asks for a few intervals of convergences and of these is the interval of convergence of e^x

Comment: @shalorsar: put this information into your question and this will enable people to formulate appropriate answers.

Comment: @shalorsar: since you have confirmed that your are asking about the series for $e^x$, I have added that to your question to make it clearer what you are asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you are asking about the interval of convergence of the series
$$
e^x=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{x^k}{k!}\tag{1}
$$
The ratio test says that the series
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k\tag{2}
$$
converges if there exists an $r\lt1$ and a $k_0$ so that for all $k\ge k_0$, we have
$$
\left|\frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k}\right|\le r\tag{3}
$$
**Hint:** In $(1)$, we have
$$
\left|\frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k}\right|=\left|\frac{x}{k+1}\right|\tag{4}
$$
Consider how $(4)$ relates to $(3)$ when $k\ge2|x|$.